# GeoFire not showing entered region swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I've tried for so many weeks to get it to work. I have read the documentation many times and there seem to be no examples of this online.

**Goal:**
All I want to be able to do is print to the console all the posts that are within a 10km radius of the current user's location.

**Issues:** I don't really understand what parameters need to placed into the `geoFire.setLocation` the user's locations or post location. The documentation only shows a manually entered coordinates. I want to pull mine from firebase and query it for when the user gets within 10km they are printed to the console. Currently, with the code I have nothing is being printed at all.

```
fileprivate func setupGeoFireLocation() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "posts")
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        guard let latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? String else { return }
        guard let longitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? String else { return }

        let postLat = (latitude as! NSString).doubleValue
        let postLon = (longitude as! NSString).doubleValue


        self.geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: postLat, longitude: postLat), forKey: "posts")
        //Not quite sure what's meant to be the "forKey:" parameter.

})
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref)

    let center = CLLocation(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
     let circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: 10.0)
    _ = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
        print(key)
    })

    circleQuery.observeReady{
        print("All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired for circle query!")
    }
}
```

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: Are you using iOS simulator ?

Comment: Using my physical device

Comment: Do I need to set location still even tho I have coordinates saved in my database? because that may be the issue I didn't use `geoFire.setlocation` @Artem

Comment: For GeoQueries to work you need to indeed set the location in GeoFire as well. GeoFire queries a separate location, where it associates keys with geohashes of the location info. Please follow the GeoFire documentation on [setting a location for a key](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#setting-location-data), [retrieving a location](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#retrieving-a-location), and [querying](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#geo-queries).

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems like you never specifically set the location information through GeoFire's `setLocation` method. For GeoQueries to work you need to indeed set the location in GeoFire as well. It won't simply work from your existing lat and lon values.

GeoFire queries a separate location, where it associates keys with geohashes of the location info. Please follow the GeoFire documentation on [setting a location for a key](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#setting-location-data), [retrieving a location](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#retrieving-a-location), and [querying](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#geo-queries).

I also recommend reading these questions that explain more about GeoFire and how it works:

- [Filtering results with Geofire + Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347571/filtering-results-with-geofire-firebase/34367340#34367340) (shows the data structure that you're missing)
- [GeoFire query on User location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301799/geofire-query-on-user-location/35302125#35302125) (shows that there are two top-level nodes: one with the geo-info only, and one with the other information. You currently only have the latter.)
- [Using GeoFire queries in Swift does not give useful output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810068/using-geofire-queries-in-swift-does-not-give-useful-output/42811267#42811267)
- [Android GeoFire onKeyEntered not trigged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823882/android-geofire-onkeyentered-not-trigged/43825830#43825830)

Comment: I've read through the documentation. Still quite unsure. Do I need to set the location to the post location or the users? and is the key just "posts" since that's my database name?

Comment: GeoFire associates a key with a location. The key is whatever (string) value you choose. If you're placing a post at a location, you'd use the key of the post (`-L...`). If you're placing a user at a location, use the ID of the user (`xgac...`). You should initialize GeoFire on a key that **it** manages completely, so that doesn't contain other data yet.